# Why do Java's synchronized Collections not use Read/Write locks?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

After stuff like `Hashtable` and `Vector` where discouraged, and when the Collections synchronized wrappers came up, I thought synchronization would be handled more efficiently. Now that I looked into the code, I'm surprised that it really is just wrapping the collections with synchronization blocks.

Why are `ReadWriteLock`s not included into, for example, SynchronizedMap in Collections? Is there some efficiency consideration that doesn't make it worth it?

Comment: Ask the designers. You'll only get guesswork here. My guess is that collections were released in 1998 or so and ReadLocks etc several years later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read-write locks are part of performance optimization, which means it can allow greater concurrency in **certain situations**. The necessary condition is, that they are applied on data structures which are **read most of the time**, but not modified.

Under other conditions they perform slightly worse than exclusive locks, which comes natural since they have a greater complexity.

It is most efficient, if the locks of a read-write lock are held typically for a moderately long time and only few modifications on the guarded resources.

Hence, whether read-write locks are better than exclusive locks depends on the use case. Eventually you have to measure with profiling which locks perform better.

Taking this into account it seems fitting to choose an exclusive lock for `Collections.synchronizedMap` addressing the general use case instead of the special case with mostly-readers.

**Further Links**

- [Starvation with ReadWriteLocks](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue165.html)
- [Refactoring Java Programs for Flexible Locking](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-msridhar/icse11.pdf)

  They wrote a tool which converts locks in a Java application automatically into `ReentrantLocks` and `ReadWriteLocks` where appropriate. For measuring purposes they have also provided some interesting benchmarking results:

[image]

> [...] However, in a conﬁguration where write operations were more
>   prevalent, the version with synchronized blocks was 50% faster than
>   one based on read-write locks with the Sun 1.6.0_07 JVM (14% faster
>   with the Sun 1.5.0_15 JVM).
>
> In a low-contention case with just 1
>   reader and 1 writer, the performance differences were less extreme,
>   and each of the three types of locks yielded the fastest version on at
>   least one machine/VM conﬁguration (e.g., note that ReentrantLocks were fastest on the 2-core machine with the Sun 1.5.0_15 JVM).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  He's asking why they weren't used in `SynchronizedMap` for example.

Comment: Thanks @platzhirsch I must say, however, I am not completely convinced that a `ReadWriteLock` is so much more costly than a standard synchronization block, and the advantages seem great. If you still ahve a minute, could you elaborate on the cost difference? thanks!

Comment: @Miquel I agree, it isn't so much more costly, as I have stated it only performs slightly worse. But that's only what I know in theory, although I came over some interesting benchmarks when I dealt with the topics, I try to add some to my answer to give concrete numbers for the cost difference.

Comment: @platzhirsch thanks a lot, the data you have added really surprised me. What a pleasure to discuss with people that know how to back their arguments!

Comment: Very interesting numbers @platzhirsch.  I don't like any Java performance test that only runs for 10 seconds tho.  Depending on the code size, the hotswap compiler may still be running.  I'd start the test, run for a minute, clear the numbers and then run for an additional time block.

Comment: But the thing I most worry about dude is that this is going to be fodder for those people trying to roll their own lock mechanisms.  For 99% of the problem space, `synchronized` is going to be recommended because you don't have to actively clear the lock.  So many people are doing premature optimization or are optimizing the wrong parts of their application.  But that said, this is something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that using `ReadWriteLock` (if that is what you are talking about) is any faster necessarily than using the `synchronized` keyword.  Both constructs impose locks and erect memory barriers and "happens before" limitations.

You may be talking about doing something smart in `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)` and friends where read methods are read locked and write methods write locked for performance.  That might work fine with the `java.util` collection classes but could cause synchronization problems with `Map`s implemented by users if the `get()` methods were being counted or something -- i.e. where a method that was "read-only" actually made updates to the collection.  Yes, doing this would be a terrible idea.

`ConcurrentHashmap` was written to be high performance and uses `volatile` fields directly instead of `synchronized` blocks.  This makes the code significantly more complicated as compared to `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)` but also faster.  That is the reason why it is recommended for high performance situations over `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<...>())`.

Comment: Oh boy. Thanks for your explanations. So where do you stand on the whole idea of `Hashtable` being discouraged, and why does `ConcurrentHashmap` "obey the same functional specification as Hashtable"? Or why was ConcurrentHashmap created instead of updating `Collections.synchronizedMap()`?

Comment: `HashTable` was written before any of the Java 1.5 concurrent classes and collections were written.  It uses method level `synchronized` statements versus the `synchronizedMap(...)` which uses an internal mutex.  It also is less efficient than `HashMap`.  It's just old code.

Comment: As my answer implied @Miquel, `ConcurrentHashMap` was written from scratch to be (as its name implies) a high performance concurrent hash map.  It has a much higher performance than `synchronizedMap(...)` since the locks are lot more fine grained.  It is also a _lot_ more complicated and has some method calls (such as `ConcurrentMap` methods) that add some useful concurrent functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the reasoning has been addressed except the following.  SynchronizedMap/Set/List as well as Hashtable and Vector rely on the collection instance being synchronized on.  As a result many developers have used this synchronization to ensure atomicity.  For instance.

```
List syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

//put if absent
synchronized(syncList){
   if(!syncList.contains(someObject)){
     syncList.add(someObject);
   }
}
```

This is thread safe and atomic for all operations since the synchronizedList will sync on itself (ie add,remove, get).  This is the main reason why the Hashtable class was not retrofitted to support lock-striping similar to the ConcurrentHashMap.

So using a ReadWriteLock for these collections would lose the ability for atomic operations unless you were able to grab the lock instances.

Comment: Sorry, I coudlnt' follow you. Why couldn't you do exactly what's on your code snippet but with a Hashtable? (Assuming you had chosen synchronizedMap instead of synchronizedList for the example)

Comment: Well you can, but my answer addresses why you cannot use a ReadWriteLock for a put if absent unless you are able to grab the write lock before the operation.  My assumption for a RWL backed colleciton is that the locks are hidden and you cannot control any extra atomic operations.

Comment: Now I got you. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3):

It is because those classes predate the read/write locks, which came into Java rather late (Java 5). They are rarely useful, anyway, due to their hardcoded fine-grained locking.

Comment: If he is talking about ReadWriteLock, that was introduced in 1.5 according to the javadocs.

Comment: Thanks guys. So, yeah, it should use them but no, it doesn't because they weren't available at the time. Fair enough. Shame though! Thanks!

Comment: Thread coordination is something that you should always do yourself, anyway. The best that a synchronized collection can do is very, very modest and limited to just a few real-world use cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing about efficiency. It's nothing wrong to use `synchronized` in `Collections.synchronizedMap`. If ReadWriteLock is used to implement the Map, I'd like to call it  `Collections.LockedMap`   ;)

Be serious, `Collections.synchronizedMap` was written years before `Lock` appears. It's an API which cannot be changed after release.

Comment: Agreed. Up until @platzhirsch brought up some of the performance measures, and Gray mentioned the lock exposure issues, it wasn't that clear to me that the API would have to change, just the internal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to [@JohnVint's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639012/1553851), consider the problem of iteration. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) explicitly requires client synchronization:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
>     ...
> synchronized (list) {
>     Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>         foo(i.next());
> }
> ```
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

This only works because the client can share the intrinsic lock on the returned map. If it were to use a read/write lock internally, the returned interface would have to support some way of accessing at least the read lock for safe iteration. That would be complicating the API for a questionable benefit (as others have explained).