# Synchronize access to HashMap from two threads in java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, collections, synchronized

I have two threads running ( One is Main Thread(Say `Thread1`) and another one is background thread (say `Thread2`)). I can access `HashMap` variable `hashMap` from `Thread1` and `Thread2`. `Thread1` modifies the `hashMap` and Thread2 reads the HashMap.

In `Thread1` code will be:

```
synchronized(hashMap){
   //updating hashMap 
}
```

In Thread2 code will be:

```
synchronized(hashMap){
     //reading hashMap
}
```

Can I synchronize the access to `hashMap` using `synchronized block` in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. But also you can use **Collections.synchronizedMap** utility method to make a hashmap thread safe:

```
Map yourMap = new HashMap();
Map synchronizedMap = java.util.Collections.synchronizedMap(yourMap);
```

Or you can use **ConcurrentHashMap** or **Hashtable** which are thread safe by default.

Comment: `Collections.synchronizedMap` makes method calls atomic, it does not make it fully threadsafe when it comes to iteration and other "multi action operations", you'll still need a `synchronized` block as described within the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) `HashTable` is exactly the same. `ConcurrentHashMap` is rather safe but it does not guarantee full threadsafety depending on your needs. You can still modify it in non-atomic ways.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [`HashTable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Hashtable) or [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap). Both these classes are synchronized so you wouldnt have to deal with it yourself.

Also, consider using a [`Lock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock).

**Do see:**

**1.** [Java Synchronized Blocks](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html).

**2.** [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

**3**. [Synchronization, Thread-Safety and Locking Techniques in Java and Kotlin](https://proandroiddev.com/synchronization-and-thread-safety-techniques-in-java-and-kotlin-f63506370e6d).

**4.** [On properly using volatile and synchronized](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/on-properly-using-volatile-and-synchronized-702fc05faac2).

Comment: I am confused. @Serdar said it can be done but you are saying exactly opposite. Can you correctly specify which is correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I would use ReadWriteLock

```
ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

void read() {
    rwl.readLock().lock();
    try {
        ... read
    } finally {
        rwl.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

void write() {
    rwl.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        ... write
    } finally {
        rwl.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Separate read / write locks make sense if you have more than 1 thread reading since they do allow any amount of reading threads while no thread is writing. I would not use them unless that is the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638233/why-do-javas-synchronized-collections-not-use-read-write-locks