# Why RW lock is slower by 100ms than synchronized in my example

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'd like to show difference in performance RW locks vs synchronized. I've done the lock part, but I got problem with `synchronized`. The `add` method is invoked by the `Producer` threads, the `getRandomElement()` is invoked by the `Consumer` threads. I would like to force that the `add()` method is executed while nobody executes `getRandomElement()` method, and that `getRandomElement()` method when nobody executes `add()` method using `synchronized` word.

Is it possible?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadSafeArrayList<E> {

    private final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Object m = new Object();

    public void add(E o) {
        synchronized (m) {
            list.add(o);
            System.out.println("Adding element by thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    public E getRandomElement() {
        synchronized (m) {
            System.out.println("Printing elements by thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if (size() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return list.get((int) (Math.random() * size()));
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

RW version which is slower for some reason, but should be faster:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class ThreadSafeArrayList<E> {
    private final ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    private final Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();

    private final Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();

    private final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(E o) {
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            list.add(o);
            System.out.println("Adding element by thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public E getRandomElement() {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("Printing elements by thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if (size() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return list.get((int) (Math.random() * size()));
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

Following classes are exactly the same in RW and synchronized versions.

The Producer class :

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    public final static int NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS = 100;
    ThreadSafeArrayList<Integer> threadSafeArrayList;

    public Producer(ThreadSafeArrayList<Integer> threadSafeArrayList) {
        this.threadSafeArrayList = threadSafeArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS; j++) {
            threadSafeArrayList.add((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
        }
    }

}
```

the `Consumer` class:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    public final static int NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS = 100;
    ThreadSafeArrayList<Integer> threadSafeArrayList;

    public Consumer(ThreadSafeArrayList<Integer> threadSafeArrayList) {
        this.threadSafeArrayList = threadSafeArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS; j++) {
            Integer obtainedElement = threadSafeArrayList.getRandomElement();
        }
    }

}
```

and the Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static long start, end;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Time of execution " + (end - start) + " milisekund");
        }));
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 100;
        ThreadSafeArrayList<Integer> threadSafeArrayList = new ThreadSafeArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Thread> consumerThreadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Consumer(threadSafeArrayList));
            consumerThreadList.add(t);
            t.start();
        }
        ArrayList<Thread> producerThreadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Producer(threadSafeArrayList));
            producerThreadList.add(t);
            t.start();
        }

        //  System.out.println("Printing the First Element : " + threadSafeArrayList.get(1));

    }

}
```

Comment: take a look at `wait/notify`

Comment: @sidgate Know those, now how they're work, yet I never know how to use them when there are more than 1 producer and 1 consumer.

Comment: it would still work, `wait` for consumer and `notifyAll` for producer task

Comment: @sidgate Like this: http://wklej.org/id/1884833/ ? I get dead lock.

Comment: @Yoda I you are using only one instance of your class(between producers and all consumers) this code should work fine.

Comment: It seems to work but for some reason it is faster than RW locks. I'll place a sample in OP in a second.

Comment: The `synchronized` is 100ms faster than RW locks. It shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Yoda While benchmarking you should do a warmup first, secondly for RW locks if you are taking write lock a lot the performance would not be good check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638233/why-do-javas-synchronized-collections-not-use-read-write-locks for some detail into the reasons for such behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Below is the approach. You might need to try out and fix the while loop. Also you might need to synchronize the list object instead of the containing class methods

```
public synchronized void add(E o) {
    try {


        list.add(o);
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Adding element by thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized E getRandomElement() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Printing elements by thread" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        while(true){
           wait();
           if(list.size()>0) break;
        }
        E ret = list.get((int) (Math.random() * size()));
        return ret;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    } 

}
```

Comment: It does not compile, after I remove unreachable catch block in add and run the program I get deadlock.